# Schatten $p$ norm for $p = \infty$

Tags: matrices, limits, normed-spaces

I am given that the definition of the Schatten $p$-norm is 
$||A||_p = \left[\text{Tr}(A^{\dagger}A)^{p/2}\right]^{1/p}$

Next we have, 
$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||A||_p = \max\{||Au||: ||u||=1\}$

1) I'm not able to see this limit and

2) How is $||..||$ in $||Au||, ||u||$ defined?

Comment: Typically in this context, $\|\cdot\|$ is defined to be the Euclidean norm.  That is, 
$$
\|u\| = \sqrt{u^\dagger u} = \sqrt{\sum_{j} |u_j|^2}
$$

Comment: What do you know about singular values?  The limit is much easier to prove if we use the fact that 
$$
\|A\|_p = [\sigma_1^p + \cdots + \sigma_n^p]^{1/p}
$$

Comment: I'm aware of the Singular Value Decomposition of a matrix but I didn't know that the p-norms can be written in terms of the entries of the SVD.

Comment: Well, now you know. All you need after that is the fact that $\|x\|_\infty = \lim_{p \to \infty} \|x\|_p$ (the notation I'm using [is used here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm)).

Comment: Can I check that the reason you can use SVD is simply because we have $Tr(A^\dagger A) = Tr(VD^\dagger U^\dagger UDV^\dagger)$ (where $A = UDV^\dagger$ is the SVD of A) due to the properties of the trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for a vector such as $$v=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{bmatrix}$$we define $||v||_p$ as $$||v||_p=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^p}$$also $$\lim_{p\to \infty}||A||_p{=\lim_{p\to \infty}(\sigma_1^p+\cdots +\sigma_n^p)^{1\over p}\\=\lim_{p\to \infty}\sigma_{\max}\left[\left({\sigma_1\over \sigma_{\max}}\right)^p+\cdots +\left({\sigma_n\over \sigma_{\max}}\right)^p\right]^{1\over p}\\=\sigma_{\max}\lim_{p\to \infty} k^{1\over p}\\=\sigma_{\max}}$$where $k$ is the multiplicity of $\sigma_{\max}$ among all the singular values. Also by a simple proof using SVD we can show that $$\max_{||u||=1}||Au||=\sigma_{\max}$$hence the result is obtained.